# Why is this still throwing the exception?

Tags: kotlin

I have a snippet of kotlin code where I'm essentially trying to ignore the exception inside the closure:

```
val remainderParts = arrayOf("/Company/Employees/Employee[Name='Michael", "Scott']/Salary", "45000")
var xpath: XPathExpression = (1..remainderParts.size).mapNotNull {
        try {
          XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(remainderParts.subList(0, it).joinToString(" "))
        }
        catch (e: TransformerException) {
          null
        }
      }.first()
```

But when the code runs, the `TransformerException` is thrown out of the block anyway. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching the wrong exception. You have to catch `XPathExpressionException`:

```
val remainderParts = listOf("/Company/Employees/Employee[Name='Michael", "Scott']/Salary", "45000")
var xpath: XPathExpression = (1..remainderParts.size).mapNotNull {
    try {
        XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(remainderParts.subList(0, it).joinToString(" "))
    }
    catch (e: XPathExpressionException) {
        null
    }
}.first()
```

If you are not sure, which exception to catch use `Exception` which is the base class of all exeptions and output the type like this:

```
// ...
catch (e: Exception) {        
    println(e::class.simpleName) // XPathExpressionException
}
```